# Found 2 files with the path - migration liquibase from 3.7.0 to 4.15.0

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase, liquibase-maven-plugin

I am migrating a spring boot app from 2.1.8.RELEASE to 2.7.7.
I am getting a liquibase error when running integrations tests with h2.

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Found 2 files with the path '../sqlFiles/file_name.sql'

```
- file:/C:/yy/yy/target/test-classes/config/liquibase/sqlFiles/file_name.sql    

- file:/C:/yy/yy/target/classes/config/liquibase/sqlFiles/file_name.sql
```

I tried `spring.liquibase.duplicateFileMode=WARN`  >>> does not work.

---

Liquibase-maven-plugin is excluded from test context, but I still get this error ?